# Laravel load JSONresource in JSONresource (parent -> child [hasMany] relationship)

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent

We have two objects. Businesses and Services. A business can have multiple services. When we fetch the business I want it to include the services in the response. Relationships are properly setup, and the BusinessResource has the proper data.

```
class Business extends JsonResource {

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'uuid'          => $this->uuid,
            'account_uuid'  => $this->account_uuid,
            'gid'           => $this->gid,
            'gid_short'     => $this->gid_short,
            'name'          => $this->name,
            'type'          => $this->type,
            'default_locale'    => $this->default_locale,
            'default_currency'  => $this->default_currency,
            'services'          => $this->services, //Loads the services straight from the DB
            'logo'              => $this->logo,
        ];
    }

}
```

Now we want to have the services formatted in their own resource.

class Service extends JsonResource {

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'uuid'                  => $this->uuid,
        'business_id'           => $this->business_uuid,
        'key'                   => $this->key,
        'value'                 => $this->value,
        'title'                 => TranslationsHelper::getTranslation(config('translatable.locale'), $this->key),
        'type'                  => $this->type,
        'frontend_adjustable'   => $this->frontend_adjustable,
        'created_at'            => $this->created_at,
        'updated_at'            => $this->updated_at,

    ];
}
```

I've tried the following.

```
'services'          => ServiceCollection::collection($this->services),
```

That throws an error :

```
Call to undefined method App\Models\BusinessService::mapInto() {"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Call to undefined method App\\Models\BusinessService::mapInto() at  App/Services/businesses/vendor/illuminate/support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php:71)
```

So now my question is..
How do you include a ResourceCollection in a parent resource?

In Laravel 8.x you should be able to do Service::make($this->services) but that throws an error: `(Exception(code: 0): Property [uuid] does not exist on this collection instance.` And yes the UUID does exist on that property.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

```
'services'          => ServiceResource::collection($this->services)
```